# Javac and java pointing to different environments

Tags: java, cmd

Please Help,
I am trying to run a compiled java class and getting errors but when I try to check my java environments it points different ways as seen below

```
c:\NetBeansProjects\Hello\src>javac -version
javac 1.7.0

c:\NetBeansProjects\Hello\src>java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)
```

According to my PC(windows 7) I have

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
jdk1.6.0_25
jdk1.7.0
jre6
jre7
```

How can I point it all to Java 7 or only Jave 6.....just want to try java 7 to see the fastness compared to java 6...hope all I have written helped.

Cheers.

Comment: What are your JAVA path variables set to?

Comment: And, that is your answer.  See below.

Comment: It also depend on sequence of value we configure in PATH variable.
So, put your sequence according to what you want to take precedence over another.

Answer (score 9):

Look at your path - I suspect c:\Windows\System32 is ahead of the JDK7 directory... and I suspect that's Java 6 for whatever reason.

Comment: @mascourt: Hmm - it's not clear where it's getting javac version 7 from at all...

Comment: I met the same problem. Java 7 is not set in PATH but still I got version7 by running the command java -version. Jon is right, java.exe is under c:\Windows\System32...

Comment: I had the same problem. I didnt have my JDK7 under the path variable but still command prompt was finding JDK7 instead of JDK6 (which I had in my path). As Grant Zhu mentioned I looked into C:\Windows\System32 and moved the java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe to another location and restarted my command prompt. Now my cmd prompt points to the exact same version of JDK 6 for both java & javac. Now I can switch to JDK7 by just replacing it with JDK6 path from the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

You have the jre/bin directory on the system path before the jdk/bin.  The javac command doesn't exist in the jre installation.

Thus the **java** command gets the version under jre6 but **javac** gets the version under jdk1.7.0.

You should change your system path to only include the one you want.  If you want to explicitly use one over the other use the absolute name (including path) instead of just the executable name.

Answer (score 3):

In the PATH variable enter C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
before the path of system32.
It fixed my problem 
Just make sure java's path is the first path in the "PATH"  environment variable

Answer (score 0):

In all likelyhood, you have installed a JDK 7 and a JRE 6 and in your PATH environment variable the JRE bin path is before your JDK bin path

Comment: So this means that your Java installation located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin is of version 1.6.0_31. Nothing strange to that. I would simply remove all installs you don't want and put the JDK you want in front of everything

Answer (score 0):

I'ts just because of your path, JRE does not contain javac and it contains java, so in your path the JRE must be located before the JDK