# Setting new path

Tags: java, path, javac

I've got this simple question that just is nagging me all day.

I have updated my JDK to `1.8.0_20` and wanted to use it's `javac`. The problem is that every single time I type `javac -verion` in `cmd`, it shows me `1.7.0_07`.

I have appended my Path with `jdk1.8.0_20\bin` and typing `java -version` in `cmd` shows `1.8.0_20`.

If you have any ideas what is going on, I will be happy to know.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609139/javac-and-java-pointing-to-different-environments) can help you?

Comment: What platform are you on? Are you also setting JAVA_HOME? Is it higher in the PATH?

Comment: Win 8.1, JAVA_HOME is set on jdk1.8.0_20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok guys, I have managed to solve the problem.

The thing was that in my path variable I had mentioned old javac (1.7.0_07), that was before latest javac path.
It wasn't so obvious, because the old javac was under 'messy' directory - connected with past uni assignment.

Thank you for help and sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

When you are typing `javac -version`, this command always show the current version of the Java compiler.

Once you have updated your JDK to `1.8.0_20` and  using it's `javac` it show the current version of that JDK which JDK path you have registered in the environment variable. so when you type `javac -version`, it show you `jdk 1.7` because in your system settings you have set the path of `jdk1.7`. So to use the latest version  of JDK either you need to set the `jdk1.8` path into your environment variable, or you need to type `set path = your directory` where your Java 1.8 is stored/path from bin`. if you use environment variable to set the path you doesn't need to set the path again and again